# Unable to get while loop working to get min and max of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I feel stupid for already having to ask questions this early into learning python but the task is this:

*Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.*

I have not started on the try/except part yet but with my current code it seems to only be running the full loop once then getting stuck on the largest number check.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break

    if largest is None or num > largest :
        largest = num
        print("large", largest)

    if smallest is None or num < smallest :
        smallest = num
        print("small", smallest)


print("Minimum is", smallest)
print("Maximum is", largest)
```

The output I get just takes the first number as min and last number as min.

```
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 17
Enter a number: 20
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: done
Minimum is 10
Maximum is 6
```

I'm stumped any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings, so it's doing a lexicographical order, where `6` is larger than `10`. You need to convert the number strings to actual numbers before comparing:

```
str_num = input("Enter a number: ")
if str_num == "done":
    break
num = int(str_num)  # Convert to integer
```